# Understanding the solution to the differential equation $x\dot y=y^{2}-4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is:

$$x\dot y=y^{2}-4$$

With the starting condition:

$$y(1)=-3$$

So I've done the separation of variables and ended up with:

$$\frac{1}{4}ln\lvert \frac{y-2}{y+2}\rvert =  ln|x|+C$$

Now in the solution, the author has defined $A\ne0$ that's a constant. This is the next step in the solution:

$$\frac{y-2}{y+2}=Ax^4$$

Now they sub in $y=-3$, $x=1$ and they find that $A = 5$.

The next steps are:

$$ \frac{y-2}{y+2} = 5x^4$$

and the answer is:

$$ y= \frac {10x^{4}+2}{1-5x^4} $$
Can anyone help me understand where the $A$ came from? and why we specifically chose $x$ to the power of $4$?  I'm assuming it's to make solving the starting conditions much easier.

Comment: $A = e^{4c}$ after multiplying by $4$ and exponentiating.

Comment: @T.Bongers Haha of course!  it just seemed to have come out of nowhere and it just seemed weird to me. Thanks for clearing up the confusion!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T. Bongers explained your question, and there is a much easier way to solve this problem by assuming that the constant $4$ is $n$.

> Let's solve, this first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation:
>
> - $$xy'(x)=y(x)^2-n$$

---

$$xy'(x)=y(x)^2-n\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)=\frac{y(x)^2-n}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2-n}=\frac{1}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2-n}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

To solve this integral, substitute $u=y(x)$ and $\text{d}u=y'(x)\space\text{d}x$:

$$\int\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2-n}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{u^2-n}\space\text{d}u=-\frac{1}{n}\int\frac{1}{1-\frac{u^2}{n}}\space\text{d}u$$

Now, substitute $s=\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\text{d}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\space\text{d}u$:

$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int\frac{1}{1-s^2}\space\text{d}s=-\frac{\text{arctanh}\left(s\right)}{\sqrt{n}}+\text{C}=$$
$$-\frac{\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}+\text{C}=-\frac{\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}+\text{C}$$

---

$$-\frac{\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}=\ln\left|x\right|+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)=-\sqrt{n}\tanh\left(\sqrt{n}\left(\ln\left|x\right|+\text{C}\right)\right)$$

So, when we know $n=4$:

$$y(x)=-2\tanh\left(2\left(\ln\left|x\right|+\text{C}\right)\right)$$

Now, we can solve $\text{C}$:

$$-3=-2\tanh\left(2\left(\ln\left|1\right|+\text{C}\right)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3}{2}=\tanh\left(2\left(0+\text{C}\right)\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=2\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2}=\text{C}$$

So, we get that:

$$y(x)=-2\tanh\left(2\ln\left|x\right|+\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to edit that a bit. After all, $-1<\tanh x<1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.